# How to save integer from Singleton in an NSUserDefault to use after app is relaunched in Xcode 5?

Tags: uiimage, singleton, xcode5

I have a Singleton that keeps track of my "score" over all my ViewControllers, and that works great. But I want to save my "score" from my Singleton in an NSUserDefault so I can use it after the app has been relaunched. My state preservation works for everything, but keeping the current score. My Singleton looses its data when the app is closed and I understand NSUserDefault saves the data between launches. I save my "score" from my Singleton to "integer" in my NSUserDefault. I then try to display an image that is named 0.png, 1.png, 2.png and so on until 10.png. But this image is displayed as 0.png every time.

(I really hope my question isn't stupid. I have read tutorials and tried different things for a week, and this is my first question here.)

Please show me where my code goes wrong.

viewcontroller.m

//Save Singleton score to NSUserDefault integer

```
[super viewDidLoad];

optionsshared = [Singleton sharedSingletonManager];
integer = optionsshared.score;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:integer forKey:@"integer"];
[defaults synchronize];


// Set Image

ScoreImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", integer]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

//Set Singleton to number from NSUserDefault in case app was terminated

```
optionsshared = [Singleton sharedSingletonManager];
NSUserDefaults *getObj = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int Number = [((NSNumber*)[getObj objectForKey:@"stars"])intValue];
optionsshared.score = Number;

[super viewDidLoad];
```

//Set image from number in NSUserDefaults

```
ScoreImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", Number]];
```

}